# How to draw a flot chart with threshold limit?

Tags: charts, flot

I would like to draw a flot chart with threshold values like below.Any suggestions pls [image: how to draw yellow and red values] description here]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used the flot dashes plugin in the past to create something similar - [Flot Dashes](https://github.com/cquartier/flot.dashes).  You will also have to specify the options for each line, have a look at this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/fZbVL/8/).

```
var dataSet = [{

data: [[1,8],[2,8],[3,8],[4,8]],
dashes: {show: true} 

},
{
data: [[1,7],[2,5],[3,6],[4,6]],

points: {show:true},
lines: {show:true}
},

{
data: [[1,4],[2,4],[3,4],[4,4]],
dashes: {show: true} 
}]
```